# Checking whether a button is enabled or not in chrome plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, plugins

I am developing a chrome plugin. It checks whether a button is enabled or not continuously. If it is enabled, it clicks on it. I am using an infinite for loop but the browser freezes. I suspect that it might not be a good idea. Here is **runscript.js** file

```
for (;;) {
  if ($('[class="abcd"]').disabled == false) {
      $('[class="abcd"]').click();
      break;
  } else {
       console.log('button disabled');
  }
}
```

and here is **manifest.json** file

```
{
  "name": "First extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "My extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_menu": "Menu",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
        "runscript.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions on how to use it correctly?

Comment: Yes, your infinite polling loop without a setInterval() is a bad idea. However, for the life of me, I can't figure out a practical use case for such a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var i = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('[class="abcd"]').prop('disabled') == false) {
      $('[class="abcd"]').click();
      clearInterval(i);
  } else {
       console.log('button disabled');
  }
}, 100);
```